# Есть ли open-source реализация клиента VPN по протоколу L2TP/IPsec(PSK)

Tags: java, android, vpn, android-ndk, l2tp

Есть ли какое-то внятное решение, библиотека, которую можно будет использовать/портировать для Android 4+ ? Пока, всё что нашёл - это исходники из самого андроида, которые для внутреннего использования.

Comment: Тут https://github.com/mikma/ipsec-android

Comment: @GVArt, я так понимаю это только ipsec? Без l2tp?

Comment: в проекте не разбирался. Но как написано в `README` только он и есть. А по факту если и не найдете. Можно скачать какие приложения с PlayMaket декомпилировать и может и найдете какие не закриптованые полезные части приложения, зависимости и тд. Хотя бы будет понятно в какую сторону смотреть

Answer (score 0):

Вполне рабочее решение, это использовать strongswan. Немного танцев с бубном для сборки, но в целом легко выделяется библиотека, со всем чем нужно.

https://www.strongswan.org/